# Showing another paper if the first paper is full with React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a paper element (div with A4 size), displaying informations enterred by the user (using Context API in Reactjs).

What I want is, in case the paper element is full of text, add another paper and display the remaining informations in it.

this is my code.

````
<Paper>
 <div class="page" data-size="A4">
  <Grid container xs={12} direction="column" justify="center"  >
   <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h5">Experiences </Typography>
   <personalInfo.Consumer>
     {( {experience} ) => (
              experience.map((exp,i) => {
                return(
                <div key={i}>
                  <Grid container xs={12} spacing={false}>
                    <Grid xs={3}>
                      <Typography className={classes.dates}>
                      {exp.startdate}-{exp.enddate}<br/>
                      {exp.city},{exp.country}
                      </Typography>
                  </Grid>
                <Grid xs={8}>
                  <Typography >
                  <h4>{exp.job}</h4>
                  {exp.employer}
                  <br/>
                  {exp.description}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </div>
              
              )})
          )}
 <personalInfo.Consumer>
</Grid>
</div>   
        </Paper>```
````

Comment: How do you want to know when paper will be full?

Comment: when its elements passes the size of A4